# SplitBy problem with Associations

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

`Association` keys are supposed to be transparent, but in this reduced example  `SplitBy` fails:

```
ds = <|t1 -> <|"a" -> 1|>, t2 -> <|"a" -> 1|>, t3 -> <|"a" -> 2|> |>
```

This works:

```
ds // Values // SplitBy[#, #a &]&
```

> {{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 1|>}, {<|"a" -> 2|>}}

But the following fail for the same reason:

```
ds // SplitBy[#, #a &] &

ds // Map[Normal] // SplitBy[#, #a &]&
```

> Split::normal: "Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in
>   !(Split[<|t1 -> {\"a\" -> 1}, t2 -> {\"a\" -> 1}, t3 -> {\"a\" ->
>   2}|>, ((#a &))[#1] === ((#a &))[#2] &]). "

Is there a workaround that doesn't involve injecting keys `t1`, `t2` etc as key-value pairs in each row?

Comment: `SplitBy` expects a `List` as the first argument, no?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SplitBy` is implemented in terms of `Split` which does not work on associations:

```
Split[ds]
```

> During evaluation of Split::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at
>   position 1 in Split[<|t1-><|a->1|>,t2-><|a->1|>,t3-><|a->2|>|>]. >>

So I think you will have to convert to a list

```
SplitBy[List @@ ds, #a &]

(* {{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 1|>}, {<|"a" -> 2|>}} *)
```

If you need to retain the keys you could use something like:

```
SplitBy[Normal@ds, #a& @* Last]

(* {{t1 -> <|"a" -> 1|>, t2 -> <|"a" -> 1|>}, {t3 -> <|"a" -> 2|>}} *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that projects the keys out and there's no easy way to sync them to the processed list.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, composing with `Last` works.

Comment: `Values` also works in place of `Last`

Comment: `associationSplitBy[f_][as_Association] := 
  SplitBy[Normal[as], f] // Map[Association];` - to wrap back up